# Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': ReferenceError: err is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I create a custom authentication for my app.

I create events login and logout, it works but I got the error on browser console :

> Exception in delivering result of invoking 'login': ReferenceError:
>   err is not defined

And my code:

```
Template.authMenu.events({
  'submit .login-form': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let email = event.target.email.value;
    let password = event.target.password.value;

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,password,() => {
      if(err) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(err.reason);
        return;
      } else {
        FlowRouter.go('/');
      }
    })
  },
  'click .logout': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout();
  }
});
```

Why I got the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loginWithPassword` callback takes should take one argument, the error, in your case it should be named `err`. See the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword).

```
Template.authMenu.events({
  'submit .login-form': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let email = event.target.email.value;
    let password = event.target.password.value;

    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,password,(err) => {
      if(err) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(err.reason);
        return;
      } else {
        FlowRouter.go('/');
      }
    })
  },
  'click .logout': (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout();
  }
});
```